# Creating an Algorithm that Shows all Possible Combinations of Numbers in a Set

Tags: python, algorithm

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days now. The program will have a set of 8 numbers like coins = [1,0,3,0,2,1,0,1] and I am trying to write it to return to me every possible set of these numbers. Such as where each element is its own count of coins and what it is returning is every possible combination of coins I can have.

For example [0,0,3,0,2,1,0,1] , [1,0,2,0,2,1,0,1] , [1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1] etc etc until all combinations are stored.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Look into `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: Check: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: It is not clear what "combinations" do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, [1,0,3,0,2,1,0,1] means you have 8 coins, 1 coin of denomination A, 3 of denomination C, 2 of denomination E, 1 of denomination F and 1 of denomination G, and you want to get all subsets of this set of coins.

You could use recursion to solve the problem for a list that is shorter (without the first entry) and then take the Cartesian product of the sets, returned by the recursive call, with all possible values for the entry that was left out. At the deepest level of recursion, the list will be empty, and then obviously there is only one combination to return: an empty list.

```
def combinations(coins):
    if len(coins) == 0:
        return [coins]
    return [[i] + combi for i in range(coins[0]+1) for combi in combinations(coins[1:])]

# example call:
print(combinations([2,0,3]))
```

Without using list comprehension, it would look like this:

```
def combinations(coins):
    if len(coins) == 0:
        return [coins]
    res = []
    for i in range(coins[0]+1):
        for combi in combinations(coins[1:]):
            res.append([i] + combi)
    return res
```